# How can I get the history of the KerasRegressor?

Tags: keras, regression, cross-validation, history

I want to get KerasRegressor history but all the time I get (...) object has no attribute 'History'
'''
# Regression Example With Boston Dataset: Standardized and Wider
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
#from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import keras.backend as K

```
# load dataset
dataframe = read_csv("Data 1398-2.csv")
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:10]
Y = dataset[:,10]

############
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.25)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.55)



##################

# define wider model
def wider_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mae'], optimizer='adam')
    #history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, batch_size=len(X), verbose=1)
    return model


# evaluate model with standardized dataset
from keras.callbacks import History 
estimators = []

estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp',KerasRegressor(model=wider_model, epochs=100, batch_size=2, verbose=0) ))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold)


print("Wider: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
#plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
#plt.title('Model loss')
#plt.ylabel('Loss')
#plt.xlabel('Epoch')
#plt.legend(['Train', 'Val'], loc='upper right')
#plt.show()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Model is at index 1 in your case, but you can also find it. Now to get history object:
`pipeline.steps[1][1].model.history.history`

If you are sure that Keras Model is always the last estimator, you can also use:
`pipeline._final_estimator.model.history.history`